# Add link text to span class name

Tags: html, jquery

I have a list of links. And I want that link texts inserts as span span data-hover names. Please tell me how can i do this. Thanks!

**What i have:**

```
<a href="#">Paris</a>
<a href="#">London</a>
<a href="#">Berlin</a>
```

**What i want:**

```
<a href="#"><span data-hover="Paris">Paris</span></a>
<a href="#"><span data-hover="London">London</span></a>
<a href="#"><span data-hover="Berlin">Berlin</span></a>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Pls show us your past attempts to do the following.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will work -

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a.className');
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].innerHTML = '<span data-hover="' + links[i].innerHTML + '">' + links[i].innerHTML + '</span>'
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Paris</a>
<a href="#" class="className">London</a>
<a href="#">Berlin</a>
```

Comment: Thank you!
But how i can use it only for links with CSS Class Name for example "Basic Links"?

Comment: You just have to access the links with specific class name instead of all the a tags in the link variable.

Comment: I updated the code to access all the links with class "className" instead of all the links.